# Highlighting columns based on day of week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, highlight, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do conditional formatting on the below example.

I would like to highlight certain columns/cells based on the day of the week.  For example, if the date is a Tuesday, then I would like the `WeHo`, `Sunset`, `WW`, `MB`, `Irvine`, `BrentW`, `Cienega` and `Hun B` columns highlighted.  If possible I would like to base the day of the week off the pre-existing date in cell A2, since we do our work one day before hand (working on a Monday, but cells are highlighted as if the actual date was Tuesday).

[image]

Comment: What did you try? That sounds like a pretty straightforward conditional formatting.  What hasn't worked?

Comment: `=WEEKDAY($A$2)+1 = 2` The number is the day of the week 1 = Sunday,7=Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the date in A2 is a Monday and you want B2:B20, E2:E20, J2:K20, Q2:Q20 and T2:U20 to be formatted then please select those ranges (with Ctrl depressed) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=WEEKDAY($A$2)=2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use formula conditional formatting. Basically, go to the formula conditional formatting and `=$A$2="Tuesday"` then click ok and make the "apply to" apply to the column you want highlighted when `A2` says it's a Tuesday.

Comment: This won't work, since in A2 is a date and not the name of the weekday.